# Confused with HTML5 FileReader

Tags: html, filereader

My understanding of the API tells me the code should be as follows to output the contents of a text file (from an Input Tag). I am not sure how to use the event object. The more I read something on Mozilla Developer docs. The more confused I get.

```
<script>
function f(event)
{
    alert("Just to check if the function is triggered");
    var r = new FileReader() ;
    r.onload = function()
    {
       alert (r.readAsText(document.getElementById['f'].files[0])) ;  
    }

}
   </script>

    <input type="file" id="f" onchange="f(event);" />
```

An change event triggers the function but nothing happens after the first line (alert message) is executed. No error messages either. Can someone help me with where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're attaching to the `onload` event but you're not doing anything that would cause the event to fire. You have to move your `readAsText()` call outside and not in the handler.

As the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload) says about `onload`:

> The FileReader.onload property contains a event handler executed when the load event is fired, when content read with readAsArrayBuffer, readAsBinaryString, readAsDataURL or readAsText is available.